# Reading pdf file names from a csv and merge pdfs

Tags: python, csv, pdf, pypdf

I have shuffled a csv file that contains file names referring to pdf files:

```
list1 = list(csv.reader(open('input.csv')))

random.shuffle(list1)
outputwriter = csv.writer(open("random.csv", "wb"))
outputwriter.writerows(list1)
```

As you can see, I also have written the result into a new csv file, but I think that is not necessary. In any case, the randomly shuffled list looks, for example, like this:

```
R001.pdf
L008.pdf
L009.pdf
L011.pdf
R006.pdf
L014.pdf
L016.pdf
R019.pdf
R021.pdf
R005.pdf
R007.pdf
L010.pdf
R004.pdf
L015.pdf
L018.pdf
L003.pdf
L012.pdf
L002.pdf
L017.pdf
L020.pdf
R013.pdf
```

What I wanted to do now was to merge these pdfs in the now random order using PyPDF2.

```
from PyPDF2 import PdfFileMerger
merger = PdfFileMerger()
for x in list1:
    merger.append(x)

merger.write("result.pdf")
```

However, this produces the following error:

```
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'seek'
```

Does anybody have an idea what I'm doing wrong? I also tried to read the list from the new random.csv like this:

```
merger = PdfFileMerger()
with open("random.csv") as f:
    r = csv.reader(f)
for x in r:
    merger.append(x)
```

This, however, also results in an error:

```
ValueError: I/O operation on closed file
```

I would be really happy to learn how to do this! :)

Comment: [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Comment: Re: that last error, Python uses a `with open..` block to automatically *close* the file when it leaves the block. That's why it complains that the file is already closed.

Answer (score 0):

`list(csv.reader(fileobj))` returns a list of lists.

[The documentation](https://pythonhosted.org/PyPDF2/PdfFileMerger.html#PyPDF2.PdfFileMerger.append) says `PdfFileMerger.append()` takes a file object argument, you are passing it lists. . Try:

```
from PyPDF2 import PdfFileMerger
merger = PdfFileMerger()
for x in list1:
    with open(x[0]) as f:
        merger.append(f)

merger.write("result.pdf")
```

Comment: Thank's for the suggestions! Unfortunately, this also leads to an error: `TypeError: coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, list found`

Comment: Aaaah! "list(csv.reader(fileobj)) returns a list of lists." That's why! Thank you for helping me understand this! :)

Answer (score -1):

You're opening files and not closing them. Whenever you use `.open()` without `.close()` there are bugs that might happen.

It's always preferred to use the context manager like you did in the last example.

`with open('filename.ext', mode='somemodeR\W')` as this automatically closes it and you don't have to worry about manually closing the file each time you open it.